# Commandline hexdump with ASCII output?

Tags: shell, unix

If I `hexdump file.txt` then I only get the hex vaules.

Would it be possible to show both hex and ASCII in text mode just like a GUI hex editor?

Comment: http://manpages.debian.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=hexdump&sektion=1  See `-C`.

Comment: Summary of the answers: Either `hd` or `xxd` will do this with no additional command-line arguments required.

Answer (score 144, accepted):

`hexdump -C` does what you want.

```
# hexdump -C /etc/passwd
00000000  72 6f 6f 74 3a 78 3a 30  3a 30 3a 72 6f 6f 74 3a  |root:x:0:0:root:|
00000010  2f 72 6f 6f 74 3a 2f 62  69 6e 2f 62 61 73 68 0a  |/root:/bin/bash.|
00000020  64 61 65 6d 6f 6e 3a 78  3a 31 3a 31 3a 64 61 65  |daemon:x:1:1:dae|
00000030  6d 6f 6e 3a 2f 75 73 72  2f 73 62 69 6e 3a 2f 62  |mon:/usr/sbin:/b|
00000040  69 6e 2f 73 68 0a 62 69  6e 3a 78 3a 32 3a 32 3a  |in/sh.bin:x:2:2:|
00000050  62 69 6e 3a 2f 62 69 6e  3a 2f 62 69 6e 2f 73 68  |bin:/bin:/bin/sh|
...
```

Answer (score 25):

The `vim` editor usually (?) includes the tool `xxd`.

```
$ xxd `which xxd` | head -n 10
0000000: 7f45 4c46 0201 0100 0000 0000 0000 0000  .ELF............
0000010: 0200 3e00 0100 0000 400a 4000 0000 0000  ..>.....@.@.....
0000020: 4000 0000 0000 0000 f035 0000 0000 0000  @........5......
0000030: 0000 0000 4000 3800 0800 4000 1b00 1a00  ....@.8...@.....
0000040: 0600 0000 0500 0000 4000 0000 0000 0000  ........@.......
0000050: 4000 4000 0000 0000 4000 4000 0000 0000  @.@.....@.@.....
0000060: c001 0000 0000 0000 c001 0000 0000 0000  ................
0000070: 0800 0000 0000 0000 0300 0000 0400 0000  ................
0000080: 0002 0000 0000 0000 0002 4000 0000 0000  ..........@.....
0000090: 0002 4000 0000 0000 1c00 0000 0000 0000  ..@.............
```

Comment: AWESOME - every distro has vim. And since `hexdump` isn't available for alpine, vim is!

Comment: +1. I try learning assembly language, and installed an old 1998 linux distro under dosbox-x in MacOS without network (mouthful setup :D ). `hexdump` version of the time simply does not show the column on the right side. and it is amazing to know `xxd` is also an old tool to be found in old distros

Answer (score 15):

`hexdump` itself will show both hex and ascii side-by-side:

```
$ date | hexdump -v -C
00000000  54 68 75 20 4d 61 79 20  20 31 20 31 36 3a 30 30  |Thu May  1 16:00|
00000010  3a 32 35 20 50 44 54 20  32 30 31 34 0a           |:25 PDT 2014.|
0000001d
```

`man hexdump` explains:

> ```
>  -C      Canonical hex+ASCII display.  Display the input offset
>          in hexadecimal, followed by sixteen space-separated,
>          two column, hexadecimal bytes, followed by the same
>          sixteen bytes in %_p format enclosed in ``|'' charac‐
>          ters.
>
>          Calling the command hd implies this option.
> ```