# Print first 100 bytes of a binary file as uint8 in Linux

Tags: javascript, linux

The following Javascript example reads and logs the first 100 bytes of a file selected by a user (via the file input):

```
var blob = file.slice(0, 100);            

var fileReader = new FileReader();
fileReader.onload = function(event) {
    var arrayBuffer = event.target.result;
    var bytes = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);
    console.log('bytes', bytes);
};

fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(blob);
```

What is the equivalent to achieve the same via a Linux utility like `hexdump` or `od`?

*UPDATE:* I am looking for `hexdump -d` but producing single byte decimals, instead of 2 byte decimals.

Comment: `hexdump` has a `-n` option to show only the requested number of bytes.

Comment: `hexdump -d` is the closest to what I am looking for. But I want single byte decimals, instead of the 2-bytes decimals that `hexdump -d` displays.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a hex dump of file containing only the hex characters without spaces in bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2614764/608639), [How to view files in binary from bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1765311/608639), [Commandline hexdump with ASCII output?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23416762/608639), etc.

Comment: `hexdump -n 100 -v -e '/1 "%02X\n"'` — `hexdump` formatting syntax is bizarre, to say the least *edit* oh wait, decimals; hold on - `hexdump -n 100 -v -e '/1 "%02d\n"'`

Comment: @Pointy Bingo. Thank you. If you can add a answer, I will accept. None of the potentially duplicate answers pointed above actually answer my question directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with `hexdump`. The formatting syntax for `hexdump` is, to say the least, somewhat weird, and the standard `man` page doesn't help much.

The tl;dr version is:

```
hexdump -n 100 -v -e '/1 "%03d\n"' your-file
```

You could use just `%d` if you don't care about leading zeros.

Now what that means:

- `-n 100` says to look only at the first 100 bytes of the input
- `-v` says to show every byte. Ordinarily, repeats are collapsed to an `*` in the output.
- `-e '/1 "%03d\n"'` is the format string (more below)

The format string consists of "stanzas" that start with a `n/m` indicator of how to count and group bytes.  `/1` means that the input should be processed in groups of 1 byte each. After the count/grouping indicator comes a format string, basically in the style of `printf()` formats.

[Here is a fairly good explanation of `hexdump` courtesy of the Suse folks.](https://www.suse.com/c/making-sense-hexdump/)